# Get 'selected tab index' on 'active tab change' - devexpress ribbon

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I am looking for a way to get the selected tab index from my Ribbon when the active tab of the ribbon is changed. I am aware that I need to have a the Client-Side Event Handler to handle this specific event, but I am quite new to JavaScript and am a bit unsure about how to get this variable (active tab index) in a JavaScript function and then pass it through to the Server-Side.

Any help appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your Ribbon:

```
<ClientSideEvents ActiveTabChanged="function(s, e) {alert(s.GetActiveTab()) }" />
```

Comment: ok, perfect that works. This makes much more sense now. Thank you!